# how to know the android version to which device is going to upgrade to

Tags: android, installation, version, upgrade, updating

I have to control to which firmware version device is going to upgrade.
For that using ActivityManager logs, I checked activity which checks whether there is any upgrade available.

It's `SystemUpdateActivity` in `com.google.android.gsf` package in `GoogleServicesFramework.apk` which checks it.
But I couldn't find code of this activity or application in framework code.

I think, `RecoverySystem.installPackage(context, packageFile)` actually installs the update.

So, if I can't modify the code of SystemUpdateActivity(which checks whether there's any upgrade available),
how can I know to which version my device is going to upgrade if upgrade is available.

My final goal is to avoid user to upgrade to certain versions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's vendor dependent.
i.e. when you click on 'Check for updates'(or similar button) from SystemUpdateActivity(this name even can be different for different vendors), it calls API to check information on vendor server and displays result to you. 
So it's almost impossible to control this as this application is provided by Vendor.

Instead we can control this when call comes to `RecoverySystem.installPackage(context, packageFile)`